# transform Relational Database Schema to Semantics Web RDF Model

Tags: c#, relational-database, rdf, transformation, semantic-web

I need to transform RDBS to an RDF model in my project. I did some research and found that Apache [Jena](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jena/info) can be helpful. However, I am not familiar with the Java platform (I am good at C++ and average at C# programming) so I tried to download Jena .Net, only to find that it is not available.

Can you give me some suggestions to give my project a head start?  Can I download Jena .Net from somewhere else?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  I edited your question to improve readability.  Also, note that questions that ask for general recommendations are note really suitable for SO, and tend not to get good answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only have to access your SQL database using a RDF way, have a look at D2RQ: http://d2rq.org/

> The D2RQ Platform is a system for accessing relational databases as
>   virtual, read-only RDF graphs. It offers RDF-based access to the
>   content of relational databases without having to replicate it into an
>   RDF store.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to make a converter from RDBS to RDF as an exercise to improve your skills on Semweb technologies or do you really need this kind of conversion for a real life project? If the latter, then you should not start with simply an RDF API. You should take a look at D2RQ, but also at what the W3C is currently defining. The [RDB2RDF working group](http://www.w3.org/2001/sw/rdb2rdf/) is working on two specifications, one for directly mapping RDB data to RDF, without further implication of the user (it's called the [Direct Mapping](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdb-direct-mapping/)) and one for specifying customised mappings, such that you can generate RDF the way you like, according to the RDF Schema you like (it's called [R2RML](http://www.w3.org/TR/r2rml/)).

At the time I'm writing, these specs are Proposed Recommendation, which is the last step before Recommendation. There are already [implementations of both specs](http://www.w3.org/2001/sw/rdb2rdf/wiki/Implementations).